# Trying to convert a date in Twig

Tags: php, date, format, twig

I'm trying to convert this:

```
{{ "26/03/2013"|date("d/m/Y") }}
```

in Twig but its is throwing the error

> Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time
>   string (26/03/2013) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character in
>   /home/vagrant/Code/Phantom
>   Website/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php on line 218.

If I pass this:

```
{{ "03/26/2013"|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

It works, so I imagine I need to change something related to Twigs date formatting

Answer (score 3):

The [date](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/date.html) filter is about formatting DateTime Object, so if you pass a string this will be passed to the constructor of the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object then to the format method, so in your case, you need to format the string that looks good for a DateTime constructor as example

```
{{ "2013-3-26"|date("d/m/Y") }}
```

From the doc:

> The format specifier is the same as supported by date, except when the
>   filtered data is of type DateInterval, when the format must conform to
>   DateInterval::format instead.

And also about string format:

> The date filter accepts strings (it must be in a format supported by
>   the strtotime function), DateTime instances, or DateInterval
>   instances. For instance, to display the current date, filter the word
>   "now":

Try [this](https://twigfiddle.com/58z21q) in this twigfiddle

Answer (score 1):

If you use `/`'s as delimiter the expected format is `m/d/Y`,
To pass the date as day, month, year you need to use a `-` as delimiter

```
{{ "26-03-2017" | date('d/m/Y') }}
```

[fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/a0vhtt)